# How to determine the egg of a python package?

Tags: python, github, pip

I have made a python package and want to include its installation in the requirements file.

After following the hitchhikers guide, my directory/repository looks like this:

```
.
├── CHANGES.txt
├── dist
│   └── Versionator-0.1.0.tar.gz
├── docs
│   └── driving_versionator.txt
├── driver_de_versionator.py
├── feedshark_learning.py
├── MANIFEST
├── MANIFEST.in
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   └── versionator.cpython-35.pyc
├── README.md
├── README.txt
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── versionator
    ├── __init__.py
    └── versionator.py

4 directories, 15 files
```

However, a similar package is installed in this way:

```
git+https://[GITHUB_TOKEN]@github.com/socialcopsdev/magneton-core#egg=magneton
```

I am unable to determine what would be the egg here in versionator?

Comment: It's what you pass as `name` parameter into the `setup(...)` function call in the `setup.py` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`pip` VCS URLs](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support) `egg=` is not an [egg](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-distribution-package) name but the name of the project. `pip` uses it to identify the project name (or name+version) before downloading.

For your project `egg` should be something like `egg=versionator` (bare name) or `egg=versionator-0.1` (name+version).

You can get name an version right from your `setup.py` with the commands:

```
python setup.py --name
python setup.py --version
```